# Using inherited types with C# collection generic type parameters

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance

I have an abstract class with a few inheriting classes like so:

```
internal abstract class SomeBaseType {}
internal class FirstSpecificType : SomeBaseType {}
internal class SecondSpecificType : SomeBaseType {}
internal class ThirdSpecificType : SomeBaseType {}
```

and a class with a constrained generic type parameter:

```
internal class SomeCollection<T> : ICollection<SomeDataStructure>
    where T : SomeBaseType {}
```

I created a `List<SomeCollection<SomeBaseType>>` and tried to add elements of various inheriting classes of `SomeBaseType` but I get the following errors ([CS1503](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zf99ds2.aspx) and [CS1950](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546088.aspx)):

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Namespace.SomeCollection<FirstSpecificType>' to 'Namespace.SomeCollection<SomeBaseType>'
The best overloaded Add method 'List<SomeCollection<SomeBaseType>>.Add(SomeCollection<SomeBaseType>)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments
```

Since `FirstSpecificType` is a `SomeBaseType`, I should be able to do this, right? It's basically the same as adding some arbitrary set of `object` to an `IList<object>`.

---

For additional context, the code where this error manifests looks like this:

```
protected Constructor()
{
    collectionOne = new SomeCollection<FirstSpecificType>();
    collectionTwo = new SomeCollection<SecondSpecificType>();
    collectionThree = new SomeCollection<ThirdSpecificType>();

    allCollections = new List<SomeCollection<SomeBaseType>>
    {
        // Each of these three collections has the error
        collectionOne,
        collectionTwo,
        collectionThree
    };
}
```

Comment: That's covariance and covariance on generic classes doesn't work.

Comment: This question is asked every day. One more time: a list of giraffes is not a list of animals. Why? Because you can put a tiger into a list of animals but not into a list of giraffes.  A list of animals is not a list of giraffes. Why? Because there might already be a tiger inside the list of animals. Therefore a list of giraffes and a list of animals are *never* compatible, because the operations you can do on those two types are different. The fact that some animals are giraffes is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue of [covariance and contravariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx), that basically says that while 
`FirstSpecificType` is indeed `SomeBaseType`, `SomeCollection<FirstSpecificType>` is **strictly not** `SomeCollection<SomeBaseType>`.

Eric Lippert wrote some fabulous [articles](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one/) about this and giraffes that I'd recommend everybody to read at least once :-)

Comment: *John Skeet wrote some fabulous articles...* ... Why not link that article as well?

Comment: @Rahul - when mixing up .net guru's, it's hard to find the right link ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and links, @Amit. That helped me figure out a new way to my goal.